# My simple HTML uploader doesn't work. WHY?

Tags: php, html, kohana

I created simple multifile uploader with html and php. I'm doing it in kohana php framework.
Here's the code:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/test/test_uploader">
    <input type="file" class="btn btn-mini" name="report_1" />
    <input type="file" class="btn btn-mini" name="report_2"  />
    <input type="file" class="btn btn-mini" name="report_3" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Zatwierdź</button>
    </form>
```

test/testuploader code:

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

When I try to upload something, it always shows:

```
Array ( 
        [report_1] => Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) 
        [report_2] => Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) 
        [report_3] => Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 )
)
```

It just doesn't upload. WHY?!

Comment: This may seem like a ridiculous question, but error 4's description is "No file was uploaded.". Did you actually specify a file to upload, and if so did you make sure you weren't trying to upload a shortcut?

Comment: yes i did, and still don't know why : /

Comment: have you tried a smaller file to ensure you're not hitting some sort of file size limitation?

Comment: Are you closing the <form> tag? In this example you are not. That could cause unpredictable behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PHP Upload Error Codes](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

> UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE
>   Value: 4; No file was uploaded.

No file arrived at the server. Did you definitely select one to upload?

Most often I see this error when trying to upload really large files (bigger than the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` php settings.) What size are the files you're trying to upload?

Comment: that sounds small, but I have seen default settings that put the max size at 1MB. Find your server's `php.ini` file and look for the two values above.